# Are there any experimental modular exponentiation algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

I am looking for something different for a modular exponentiation calculation, than the the 
- montogmery
- frobenius
algorithm.

Are there any faster algos? (Reduce the Question to $\mathbb F_{p^n}$, where $n \leq 12$ and p @512-1024 bit.
Or are there some "hardware hacks" or tweaks on microcontroller like the STM32F4 with Cortex M4?